# Three.js CTM object load with Orbicontrol changes focus on object

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

I started to play around with three.js. I have decided to use THREE.CTMLoader() to load in my objects.

I had a PerspectiveCamera set up with OrbitControls. It was working perfectly when I used other 3D object loading methods like .obj or .js.

Now it rotates the 3D objects instead of move the camera.

I think its more of a general issue, just wondering if anyone encountered with anything similar.

Some code for clarification:

```
//camera    
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 300;
            camera.position.y = -500;

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

//model load

var loader = new THREE.CTMLoader();

loader.load( "3dobjects/blue.ctm",   function( geometry ) {

   var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "3dobjects/blue.jpg" ), combine: THREE.MixOperation } );
                geometry.name = "blue";
                callbackModel( geometry, 20, material, -150, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

            }, { useWorker: true } );
```

I will want to juts move the camera on 2 planes instead of all 3 so I guess I will need to write my own camera control instead of using the orbit control, but  it is still interests me. What did go wrong?

**Edit:**
It seems like the camera orbit size(r) turned to 0. Maybe it is a better description.

**Edit2:**

```
function callbackModel( geometry, s, material, x, y, z, rx, ry ) {

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
            mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
            mesh.rotation.x = rx;
            mesh.rotation.z = ry;

            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;

            scene.add( mesh );
            objects.push( mesh );

        }
```

Comment: what does your callbackModel do?

Comment: @antont Just set the location/rotation of the object adds it to the mesh and to an object list, please see Edit2 for code